# Why is blender lagging when rigging bones in my armature?

Tags: rigging

I started working on a rig for my first 3D anime model, and everything was running smoothly up until then. As I finished with the body I noticed that suddenly every time I moved the model in pose mode or tried to make an edit in edit mode, it would lag really bad. There isn't any lag when I edit the meshes or spin the camera around, it's only lagging when I'm trying to edit, move, or add bones in the edit or pose mode of my armature. I'm fairly certain that I must have made a mistake when making my rig that caused this, but I don't know what it could've been. What are some common mistakes that can cause this and what are the ways to solve these issues?

Comment: happens to me too, I assumed it's just intensive operations (or inefficient implementation?) but if someone knows ways to overcome this then I'd like to know as well. btw you might have modifiers which have to recalculate every redraw, so that might be part of it?

Comment: It would help to see a blend file that shows this problem, because there are many possible causes and each has a different solution. ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is there a size limit for blend files? mine is currently stuck at 30-40% and it's just 1 gig